# Close current window using ctrl+w

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I have a Java program that uses a bunch of `JFrame` objects. To make it easier to clean up desktop, I want to implement that the current focused window can be closed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd>.

I tried to use a keybinding (in the superclass of any view) whose `Action`'s `actionPerformed` method contains this:

```
frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
```

This works quite well – as long as I use only one window. It only works, when the last-opened frame is focused, and it only closes that one.

---

My question is:

1. *Why* does the keybinding behaves like this? (I guess it's by design.)
2. How to create a keybinding per frame without adding any single component to a `KeyListener`.

Comment: Register your key bindings on root pane of the frame with the modifier `JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`. Something like `frame.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)`

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: What's wrong with CTRL+F4!?

Comment: @MadProgrammer The fact that CTRL+F4 does nothing? (I just tried.)

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy Thank you for  the modifier idea!

Comment: @Asqiir, How about Alt+F4? Did you try clicking on the "system menu" at the top/left of your frame to see what the default keystroke is? A LAF will have a default close keystroke. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @camickr It doesn't show me, which one is the default closing keystroke is.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy your comment is a perfect answer to 2. Thanx!

Comment: @Asqiir `It doesn't show me, which one is the default closing keystroke is.` - that is surprising. I use Windows and it shows "Close" as the menu name and "Alt+F4". I thought each LAF should have a "Close" menu option.

Comment: @camickr I use Linux. Xubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does the keybinding behaves like this? (I guess it's by design.)

I'd guess you're doing something wrong, but without any kind of example code, it's impossible to know what

> How to create a keybinding per frame without adding any single component to a KeyListener

There's a number of ways you might use to achieve this...

## Global based solution...

One approach is to take a "global" approach, using a system which doesn't rely on you extending from a root solution, but which can be applied to just about any existing or future project.

### `AWTEventListener`

One solution might be to attach a `AWTEventListener` to the `Toolkit`.  This is quite low level and provides you access into the ALL the key events which the system is processing

```
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.AWTEventListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.FocusManager;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    private int count = 0;
    private int xPos = 10;
    private int yPos = 10;

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                installKeyboardMonitor();
                for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
                    makeWindow();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void installKeyboardMonitor() {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
                KeyEvent ke = (KeyEvent) event;
                if (ke.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED) {
                    System.out.println("Pressed");
                    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                        System.out.println("W Key");
                        if (ke.isControlDown()) {
                            System.out.println("Control down");
                            Window window = FocusManager.getCurrentManager().getActiveWindow();
                            if (window != null) {
                                window.dispose();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }, AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
    }

    public void makeWindow() {
        count++;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test " + count);
        frame.setContentPane(new JPanel(new BorderLayout()) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(200, 200);
            }
        });
        frame.add(new JLabel("Window " + count));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(xPos, yPos);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        xPos += 100;
        yPos += 100;
    }

}
```

### `KeyEventDispatcher`

This is slightly less low level then the `AWTEventListener` but it focus only on `KeyEvent`s which makes it a little easier to manage, but is essentially the same idea

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.FocusManager;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    private int count = 0;
    private int xPos = 10;
    private int yPos = 10;

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                installKeyboardMonitor();
                for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
                    makeWindow();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void installKeyboardMonitor() {
        KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {
            @Override
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent ke) {
                if (ke.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED) {
                    System.out.println("Pressed");
                    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                        System.out.println("W Key");
                        if (ke.isControlDown()) {
                            System.out.println("Control down");
                            Window window = FocusManager.getCurrentManager().getActiveWindow();
                            if (window != null) {
                                window.dispose();
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    public void makeWindow() {
        count++;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test " + count);
        frame.setContentPane(new JPanel(new BorderLayout()) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(200, 200);
            }
        });
        frame.add(new JLabel("Window " + count));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(xPos, yPos);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        xPos += 100;
        yPos += 100;
    }

}
```

## Configurable solution

Another solution is to provide a "configuration" based solution.  This is similar to the concept of having a base component, but frees you from been locked into a single extension point.

This approach is a little more troublesome, as you actually need to remember to apply to every window and dialog your application might create.

It simply uses the Key Bindings API to register a binding against the windows `JRootPane`, but you could use just about any component which you know isn't going to be removed from the window.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    private int count = 0;
    private int xPos = 10;
    private int yPos = 10;

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
                    makeWindow();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void installKeyBindings(JComponent component) {
        InputMap inputMap = component.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap actionMap = component.getActionMap();

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK), "Window.close");
        actionMap.put("Window.close", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(component);
                if (window != null) {
                    window.dispose();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void makeWindow() {
        count++;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test " + count);
        installKeyBindings(frame.getRootPane());
        frame.setContentPane(new JPanel(new BorderLayout()) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(200, 200);
            }
        });
        frame.add(new JLabel("Window " + count));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(xPos, yPos);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        xPos += 100;
        yPos += 100;
    }

}
```

## After thoughts

This is just three possible solutions.  It wouldn't take to much effort to provide a more configurable based solution around each one (so you could supply the key stroke), but I'll leave that up to you